# cloudinary django database error

Tags: python, django, database, cloudinary

I am developing app that uses Cloudinary, using Django 1.8.
I downloaded the sample project from https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-django-sample.
This line:
    image = CloudinaryField('image')

causes an error when runnig "manage.py migrate" saying

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "None": syntax error

Tried adding "null=True" and "blank=True" to the field definition

```
image = CloudinaryField('image', null=True, blank=True)
```

but I am getting the same result.
I import cloudinafield like this

> from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField

When I comment out the line with CloudinadyField there are no errors.
What can be the reason of this error?

Comment: Please show the whole error and traceback.

Comment: Please make sure you use the latest version of the cloudinary SDK (currently 1.1.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like an idiot, just updated cloudinary library to 1.1.3 and everything works fine now. Thanks Tal Lev-Ami

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no such field type like the one you used.

For handling image you can either use `CharField` to store the url or use `FileField` to store the file key which will link the url.

You can find detailed configuration on [this](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_integration) page.

Comment: CloudinaryField is a part of cloudinary's library

Comment: from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField.   The problem is that django can't create records in database and I can't understand why